# Header image resize

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I need some help , when i resize the windows the image don't resize with good height or width ,i'am using WordPress theme twenty seven and i use the follow code to reduce height and remove amination ,of header image in twenty seventeen theme. pic related

```
.has-header-image .custom-header-media img, 
.has-header-video .custom-header-media video, 
.has-header-video .custom-header-media iframe, 
.has-header-image:not(.twentyseventeen-front-page):not(.home) 
.custom-header-media img {
height: 66% !important;
object-fit: fill !important;
width: 100%;
max-height: 100% !important;
display: block !important;
position: relative !important;
}

#wp-custom-header {
height: 100% !important;
}
```

[image: with object-fit: contain !important;]
[image]

Comment: try adding `max-width: 100%` to the `img`

Comment: i already have this in my `img` 
    `max-width: 100% !important;
    max-height: 100% !important;
    display: block !important;
    position: relative !important;
}`

Comment: No you don't... not in the CSS you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>`height: 66% !important;`</s>

The set height value is what distorts your header image.

EDIT: Try `object-fit: contain !important;` and tell me whether or not it works.

EDIT_2: Remove any height you have set on your img and the gray should disappear.

EDIT_3: Tell me how it goes and mark this answer as correct if I have helped you and it will help others having the same problem too.

[image: One]

---

Get rid of the height you have set on the image.

```
#wp-custom-header > img {
  height: auto !important;
}
```

[image: Two]

---

Remove the extra space.

```
.custom-header {
  height: 25vw !important;
}
```

[image: Three]

Comment: i remove but i still have the problem when i resize the windows to small windows the `img` still with height problem.

Comment: Dubosky, I edited my answer. Try it again and tell me how it goes!

Comment: its working , but it is showing new problem the gray space in image i need remove him now, i insert new image.

Comment: I edited my answer again. Try removing any height you have set on your img in the CSS. Tell me if it works.

Comment: As i said , is wordpress , i already try to edit the father theme CSS , but the problem persists  the follow code is father theme header css :`.has-header-image .custom-header-media img,
.has-header-video .custom-header-media video,
.has-header-video .custom-header-media iframe {
 position: fixed;
 height: auto;
 max-width: 1000%;
 min-height: 100%;
 min-width: 100%;
 min-width: 100vw; /* vw prevents 1px gap on left that 100% has */
 width: auto;}`

Comment: Send me a link to the website and I can help you find the problem. At this point, i'm just guessing cause there's no code snippet nor JSFiddle.

Comment: i didnt find  `.custom-header {
  height: 25vw !important;
} ` can u check again

Answer (score 2):

You can safely set the images to a min-width and min-height using pixels like

```
img{
    max-width: 420px !important;
    max-height: 270px !important; 
    width:100%
    display: block !important; 
    position: relative !important; 
   }
```

---

To make the image resize you could use bootstrap by adding the following lines in between the head tags and add the class img-responsive to the intended image.

(SINCE YOU ARE USING WORDPRESS YOU WONT BE NEEDING THE BELOW AS WP ALREADY INCLUDES BOOTSTRAP)

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Those links were copied from https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp , you will also find a very good tutorial on how to use bootstrap there.

And to answer the comment you have added,
please use the following css code and remove the  tag from the html code in div class="wp-custom-header" and instead use the following css code

```
.wp-custom-header{
 background-image: url('http://web.ipca.pt/poliempreende/wp-
 content/uploads/2017/05/Logo-IPCA-Poliempreende.png');
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size: 'find out which size you want';
 }
```

Comment: but the i try           `max-width: 420px !important;
                              max-height: 270px !important;` the image still not resize for small windows(mobile windows)

Comment: Yeah please give it a try, just don't forget to add the class img-responsive to the image

Comment: Yeah please give it a try, just don't forget to add the class img-responsive to the image

Comment: i try but , it only rezise the fonts

Comment: did you use the class img-responsive ??? also if that doesn't work we could easily hard code, i have edited my answer for you

Comment: its working for some images , thanks ,but for another image still not work

Comment: Could you paste here the code of the images that are not resizing?

Comment: here is the link of the site :http://web.ipca.pt/poliempreende/ but when i resize the windows the image dnt resize and is showing gray spaces

Comment: adding an image in a div and expecting it to act like a background isnt exactly the best thing.

at div .wp-custom-header please remove the img tag and instead use the following css code i have included in my answer.